# Mongoose - Proper way to initialize nested Schemas

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

If I have 3 models, one nested in another like below, how do I properly initialize  them in my seed data function?

---

```
var Alpha = mongoose.Schema({
  Beta: [Beta],
  A_Field: {type: String}
});
```

---

```
var Beta = mongoose.Schema({
  Charlie: [Charlie],
  A_Field: {type: String}
});
```

---

```
var Charlie = mongoose.Schema({
  A_Field: {type: String}
});
```

---

```
function createSeedData(data) {
   Alpha.find({}).exec(function (err, collection) {
       if (collection.length === 0) {
           data.forEach(function (item) {
          Alpha.create(

           //Alpha's A_Field
           //Beta's A_Field
           //Charlie's A_Field

           )
       }
```

Comment: Changed the way you worded this because the term "populate" has a different meaning in mongoose. Also please don't use bold text or headings around your sentences.

Comment: This is all subjective to the data structure of your "data" input. If It matches the structure of your nested schema then all you need to do it pass it directly into `.create()`. Otherwise it is again possibly easiest to "manipulate" any other structure so that it does match and then just pass it in again. You can do that with embedded models since all data is in the same document.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**As usual, the answer is always simplier than I originally thought:**

**schemas:**

```
var Alpha = mongoose.Schema({
  Beta: { type: Schema.ObjectId, ref: 'Beta' },
  A_Field: {type: String}
});
```

---

```
var Beta = mongoose.Schema({
  Charlie: { type: Schema.ObjectId, ref: 'Charlie' },
  B_Field: {type: String}
});
```

---

```
var Charlie = mongoose.Schema({
  C_Field: {type: String}
});
```

---

**seedData.js**

```
var 
   Alpha = require('../models/alpha.server.model'),
   Beta = require('../models/beta.server.model'),
   Charlie = require('../models/charlie.server.model'),
   data = require('../json/data');

   createCharlie(data);
   createBeta(data);
   createAlpha(data);
```

---

```
  function CreateAlpha(data){
    data.forEach(function(item){
      var alpha = new Alpha({
       // no _id designation, mongo will create
       Beta : item.betaId,
       .....
      }).save(function (err) {
         if (err) {
            console.log(err);
        });
     }}
```

---

```
   function CreateBeta(data){
     data.forEach(function(item){
      var beta = new Beta({
      _id : item.betaId,
      Charlie = item.charlieId,
      .....
   }).save(function (err) {
       if (err) {
         console.log(err);
            }
        });
  }}
```

---

```
   function CreateCharlie(data){
     data.forEach(function(item){
        var charlie = new Charlie({
        _id = item.charlieId,
        ....
       }).save(function (err) {
         if (err) {
                console.log(err);
            }
        });
    }}
```

**JSON:**

```
 [
  { "betaId": xxxx, "charlieId": xxxx, "A_Field":"AAA", "B_Field":"BBB", "C_Field":"CCC"}
 ]
```